Using Multiple Threads/Processes to Parse Very Large Files
I'm creating a Blazor WebAssembly app and it basically reads in a file of around 500,000 lines, breaks each line - or group of lines - into an object and makes changes accordingly) then outputs that array (MemoryStream) to a file.
Currently I loop through my array and build out a long string then use
MemoryStream fileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetByteCount(longString));
How can I optimally loop through the 500,000 lines, parse them and build this stream via multiple processes/threads and make sure the final stream is in the same order (all lines include a timestamp and have to be chronological)? What I have works but it's excruciatingly slow.

If the output needs to be in input order, then you can't really do multiprocessing.  I guess if they are timestamped, you could sort the result when it's done.

One thread would read the file and break it into sections that can be processed individually (lines?) and submit each of them to a thread pool so that they can be processed concurrently.

Caution-- multi-threading currently isn't supported on most devices and browsers.  Be careful with your deployment.

More details are needed so we can really help you. The slow part should be the actual parsing but not much information are provided about it (unless you mean that the provided line is a bottleneck which would be a bit surprising). Sometimes, an aggressively-optimized sequential code is enough (and is the best if there is no proper multi-threading support).
